# Adding legends to plots when not using the pyplot interface

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say I have the following:

```
fig  = figure()
ax   = f.add_subplot(111)

# my_values holds a 2D numpy array
lines = ax.plot(my_values)
```

Say that for **each** column of `my_values` I have a string holding the legend that I want associated with the corresponding line.

e.g.

```
my_legends = ['foo ' + str(x) for x in xrange(my_values.shape[1])]
```

I have the handles for the figure (`fig`), axes (`ax`) and the lines (`lines`), how can I add these legends to the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `ax.legend`:

```
ax.legend(lines, my_legends)
```

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig  = plt.figure()
ax   = fig.add_subplot(111)
my_values = np.cumsum(np.random.random(100)-0.5).reshape(-1, 2)
lines = ax.plot(my_values)
ax.legend(lines, ['eenie', 'meenie'], loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]